# Convert date9. to character

Tags: sas

I'm trying to convert a sas date9. date to a character variable, 
but the problem, I guess, is that date9. actually has a numeric "julian" value, so when I try to pass it to a character variable, it dismisses the date9. format and becomes a number ("21635").

In other words, I have a variable date9. = 27MAR2019, with the value "21635", and I want a character variable char = "27MAR2019".

I tried using both put and input functions, but they only use the 'julian' value.

Can anyone give me a hand?

Comment: Show the statement you wrote using PUT function.

Comment: data _null_;

 dt = '27-03-2019';

 format datevar1 date9.;

 datevar1 = input(dt, DDMMYY10.);

 datevar2 = cat("'", datevar1, "'d"); 

 put datevar1;

 put datevar2;

run;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you are showing is the number of days since 1960. That is how SAS stores dates. If you want the FORMATTED value of a variable instead of the raw value of the variable you need to ask for it.  For example by using the PUT() function

```
 newvar=put(oldvar,date9.);
```

or the VVALUE() function.

```
 newvar=vvalue(oldvar);
```

Comment: I tried with the first option, and it did work perfectly! Thankss : )

Comment: Interestingly I did the same thing today.